# How to copy Visio 2019 Professional shapes to Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I just got Visio 2019 Professional but I am unable to copy shapes from it and paste it in PowerPoint. I was able to do it before I updated Visio.

Shapes in Visio:

[image]

Partial picture in PowerPoint:

[image]

Comment: 1. Is the Powerpoint image you show an example of what you were able to do before the update, or what happens now?  2. Is the issue the ability to copy and paste individual shape objects as shape objects, or the ability to copy and paste an image of the composite Visio diagram?

Comment: The Powerpoint image is what happens now.The issue is, I can't copy the shape objects and paste a complete image. If there is a way to actually paste shape objects in Powerpoint, it is more welcome.

Comment: May it be the new "Power Point Snippets" feature? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-powerpoint-presentation-from-visio-e7da404b-4208-49d1-9518-6fe1a4723657

Comment: The pasted image appears to have resize handles. What happens if you resize the image?

Comment: It distorts the image if I resize.